# Unable to include the physics package

Tags: physics

I get an error message on 64-bit MikTex for the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}
\begin{document}
Hello world
\end{document}
```

What can be possibly going wrong? I tried everything I know.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.Package: physics 

(./xparse.sty (./expl3.sty
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3names.sty
Package: l3names 2017/03/18 Obsolete L3 package

Comment: Right, so it seems that both `xparse.sty` and `expl3.sty` is found in the *same folder* as your `.tex` file. Which is wrong, those should also be in `c:/texlive/...`. The first place LaTeX looks for files is, I think, the current folder. So presumably, if you delete those local copies of `xparse` and `expl3` (or even have the `.tex` file in a different folder), it would work.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63646/discussion-on-question-by-avi-unable-to-include-the-physics-package).

Answer (score 2):

Your `.log` file seems to show that both `xparse.sty` and `expl3.sty` are located in the *same* folder as your `.tex` file, while they should have been in `c:/texlive/2017/...`, as is the case with `l3names.sty`. The first place LaTeX looks for files is, I think, the current folder. So presumably, if you delete those local copies of `xparse` and `expl3` (or even have the `.tex` file in a different folder), it would work.